# Setting an existing value for dropdown in MVC C# with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlist

I have a dropdown list rendered from a database, just need to be able to set an existing value (if it exists). _jobService.GetTenancyForJob gets a value if one already exists and the other service just returns an id and value for each item. I need to be able to set the selected list item here in the controller but just struggling with the syntax (yeah it's using viewbag just for testing will be using ViewModel).

I've done this before in a wide variety of ways just wondering how it would be done in this scenario... Any pointers appreciated.

```
var jobTenancies = _jobService.GetTenancyForJob(id);
var getTenancies = _jobService.GetAllJobTenancies();

var tenancyList = getTenancies.Select( t => new SelectListItem()
{
  Text = t.JobTenancyName, 
  Value = t.Id.ToString()
}).ToList();
tenancyList.Insert(0, new SelectListItem() { Text="", Value = "" } );
Viewbag.TenancyList = tenancyList;
```

Edit: in the view

```
<div class="control-group">
  @Html.BootstrapLabelFor(model => model.TenancyName)
  <div class="controls">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.TenancyId, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.TenancyList)
    @Html.BootstrapValidationMessageFor(model => model.TenancyId)
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show the view. If your binding to a property and the value of that property matched one of the option values then it will be selected. And DONT add the label option by inserting a `SelectListItem`. Use the overload of `@Html.DropDownLstFor()` that accepts the label option.

Comment: Added in the view code..

Comment: If the values in the options are (say) 1 - 10, and the value of your model property `TenancyId` is (say) 2, then the second option will be selected when the view is displayed. And change the controller code to `Viewbag.TenancyList = new SelectList(getTenancies, "Id", "JobTenancyName");` and the view to `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TenancyId, (SelectList)ViewBag.TenancyList, "-Please select-")` to generate the `null` option

Comment: Thanks Stephen, got it working on your advice. if you add your comment as an Answer I will mark as correct. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the value of property `TenancyId` in the controller before you return the View. If the value matches the value of one of your options then that option will be selected when the view is displayed. Note also you should not be adding a 'empty' option by inserting an additional `SelectListItem` (which adds `<option value="">`), but rather use the overload of `DropDownListFor()` that accepts `optionLabel` which correctly adds an option with a `null` value (`<option value>`). As you indicated you intend to use a view model, it might include

```
public class TenancyVM
{
  [Required(ErroMessage = "Please select tenancy")]
  [Display(Name = "Tenancy")]
  public int? TenancyID { get; set; }
  ....
  public SelectList TenancyList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
  TenancyVM model = new TenancyVM();
  model.TenancyID = jobService.GetTenancyForJob(id);
  ConfigureEditModel(model);
  return View(model);
}

// Gets called in the GET and in POST method if the view is returned
private void ConfigureEditModel(TenancyVM model)
{
  var tenancies = _jobService.GetAllJobTenancies();
  model.TenancyList = new SelectList(tenancies , "Id", "JobTenancyName");
}
```

View

```
<div class="control-group">
  @Html.BootstrapLabelFor(m => m.TenancyID)
  <div class="controls">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TenancyID, Model.TenancyList, "-Please select-")
    @Html.BootstrapValidationMessageFor(m => m.TenancyID)
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to cast your ViewBag data to SelectList as follow:

```
var data =  (SelectList)Viewbag.TenancyList;
```

You need to do this because ViewBag carry object data type.
After casting you can get your tenacyList from data.Items.

Comment: The ViewBag property is `List<SelectListItem>` and OP has cast it to `List<SelectListItem>` in the html helper!